# .NET Core claims unavailable when referred from other site

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims

I noticed the original problem when trying to integrate stripe payment to the system. The user is logged in and after filling up necessary details is sent to stripe page to complete the payment.

After successful payment, he is redirected to the site. Here I needed to access certain claims about the user and I expected to find them from `HTTPContext.Request.Identity.Claims`.

However, there were no claims and even `HTTPContext.Request.Identity.Name` was empty.

Here is the `startup.cs` and controller code.

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Customer>(
               cm => {
                   cm.AutoMap();
                   cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
               });

            var mcaMongoDbConfig = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SiteMongoDbConfig)).Get<SiteMongoDbConfig>();

            var mongoDbSettings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SiteMongoDbConfig)).Get<SiteMongoDbConfig>();
            services.AddIdentity<Customer, ApplicationRole>().AddDefaultUI()
                .AddUserManager<UserManager<Customer>>()
            .AddMongoDbStores<Customer, ApplicationRole, Guid>
            (
                mongoDbSettings.ConnectionString, mcaMongoDbConfig.Name
            )
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<Customer>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
}
```

The controller is pretty simple so far:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    protected HttpContext context;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var httpContext = context;
        //context.Request.Identity.Name
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

The user is redirected to the index view from external site where I need to access claims. It is a simple HTML file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href ="https://localhost:43256"/>go back</a>
   </body>
```

The claims are available when the user is visiting the page from within the site but not when the user is redirected to the page from an external link..

Answer (score 0):

One theory could be that the cookies are lost when you redirect from your app -> stripe and back. This is due to the SameSite cookie security feature that all browsers today support.

I would check if the cookie is included in the request after the user paid at stripe.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: The cookies are on the disk. However, not available in particular cases. Once I am on the page, on refresh, the user is logged in and cookies are available. I do not have to login again. Visually, there is nothing wrong but I am unable to access claims etc..

Comment: The cookies could be there, but they are not always included in requests due to the same site flag. That is a potential problem.